# Qual è il significato di "tagliare di grasso" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning, idioms, regional

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> «Una buona parte della mia terra io la lascio germa: per il pascolo... Non posso dire dunque quanto mi rende per ettaro quella lasciata germa: posso dire quanto mi rendono le pecore... A **tagliare di grasso**, mezzo milione... Il resto, in grano, fave, mandorle e olio, secondo le annate...».

In [questo dizionario](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/gelo.htm) ho trovato che l'aggettivo "germo" è di origine dialettale e si usa per indicare un terreno incolto, cioè quello che sarebbe qualificato come "en friche" in francese. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "tagliare di grasso" e ricercando su Google non ho trovato niente a riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il **substrato dialettale della lingua di Sciascia** coesiste con un registro colto lessicale e sintattico. Lo strato colto affiora nell’uso di termini marcatamente letterali e connotati temporalmente, mentre non mancano sicilianismi e anacoluti: essi confermano la scelta per una lingua non monolitica, da adeguare alle varie situazioni comunicative, e lontana da fobie puristiche.

Nel caso in questione Sciascia ripropone un detto siciliano **tagghiari grassu** che vuol dire

- *[scialacquare, sciupare](https://books.google.it/books?id=3fyBCeDykm0C&pg=PA1011#v=onepage&q&f=false)*;
- *[abbondare, esagerare](https://www.google.it/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&biw=1280&bih=572&tbm=bks&ei=R_FCWoXJKMfyUr7Pr-gI&q=tagghiari+grassu+abbondare&oq=tagghiari+grassu+abbondare&gs_l=psy-ab.3...18982.23211.0.23362.9.9.0.0.0.0.117.912.5j4.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Y8BI7NaJVTk)*;
- *[far checchesia, e particolarmente i conti, con larghezza](https://books.google.it/books?id=3-MlAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA401&dq=a+tagghiari+grassu&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNvuTj_ajYAhUBOxQKHb6DAzUQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=a%20tagghiari%20grassu&f=false)*,

Sciascia lo rende letteralmente con *taliare grasso*, che tuttavia in italiano non ha significato se non quello letterale, ma che nessuno capisce (forse intuisce...).

In questo caso l'espressione **a tagliare di grasso**  indica un'espessione avverbiale che potremmo identificare con "**ad abbondare, ad esagerare, a fare i conti per eccesso**".

Answer (score 2):

In questo caso **tagliare di grasso** significa fare una stima grossolana e approssimativa.

Non può infatti stimare quanto gli renderà il campo incolto ma le pecore sì, in quanto la valutazione è fattibile più facilmente.

Si potrebbe anche dire a ***occhio e croce*** e il significato sarebbe all’incirca lo stesso.

Comment: Curioso che non si trovi nessun riferimento a questa espressione su Google!