# Cosa significa "tagliare giù di grosso"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Insomma, gli era presa quella smania di chi racconta storie e non sa mai se sono più belle quelle che gli sono veramente accadute e che a rievocarle riportano con sé tutto un mare d'ore passate, di sentimenti minuti, tedii, felicità, incertezze, vanaglorie, nausee di sé, oppure quelle che ci s'inventa, in cui si **taglia giù di grosso**, e tutto appare facile, ma poi più si svaria più ci s'accorge che si   torna a parlare delle cose che s'è avuto o capito in realtà vivendo.

Mi potreste spiegare il significato dell'espressione "tagliare giù di grosso" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato alla voce "tagliare" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato niente a riguardo. Non so se abbia qualcosa a che vedere con [questo](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8801/707).

Comment: "Di grosso" significa grossolanamente; tagliare in questo caso è secondo me nel senso di "abbreviare, ridurre o togliere allo scopo di abbreviare", e intende quel tipo di storie raccontate in modo sbrigativo, magari in cui intere parti sono abbozzate, in quanto appunto essendo in parte o del tutto inventate non si può abbondare coi particolari.
Cfr anche il modo di dire "non andare per il sottile"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tagliare (giù di) grosso" significa approssimare, abborracciare. Vedi la Legge Fondamentale dell'Incastro: "*Taglialo grosso e infilalo a calci*" (Arthur Block).

Non è più molto usato - su Google Books l'ho trovato, con il significato di "abborracciare", su *La Stirpe - Rivista delle Corporazioni Fasciste* (1932)

> ...ma debbo pur dirle che non posso dare in due mesi compiuta la vita dell'Ariosto. Se io fossi sicuro di accomodare e di **tagliare grosso** con la mia coscienza di scrittore e con il rispetto dell'arte, butterei giù di quella roba come tanta se ne fa oggi, intascherei le mille lire e a luglio me ne andrei viaggiando a mio diletto...

e così in un romanzo di Emilio Salgari:

> Kammamuri si era appena svegliato e stava seduto dinanzi ad una grossa cesta che conteneva carne fredda, legumi, pane e birra: era la *tiffine*, o colazione mattutina a cui dava l'assalto. – Ve n'è anche per voi – disse al malabaro ed al *rajaputo*. – Il gran cuoco del *maharajah* è abituato a **tagliare grosso** e abbondare.

Proprio nel senso di "inventare", negli *Annali dell'Istituto Italiano di Studi Storici*:

> ...non restava in realtà che il gusto per la divagazione, per giunta non sempre sincera (Dionigi stesso ammetteva che Teopompo amasse «**tagliare grosso**» [...]). Così, quando Teopompo presenta il popolo dei Macedoni come un'orda di ubriaconi, di barbari, di...

In questo caso significa che la storia è inventata e parte con approssimazioni, "in cui tutto appare facile"; ma quando si va a ricamare, a svariare, a definire la storia, quei dettagli anche involontariamente li si prende dalla propria esperienza, e la storia "inventata" ritorna ad essere una storia con elementi reali: "*ci s'accorge che si torna a parlare delle cose che s'è avuto o capito in realtà vivendo*".

La locuzione **tagliare di grosso** nel significato di *approssimare per eccesso*, e dunque *andare per le spicce*, *esagerare*, sembra venire dal lessico agricolo ed è anch'essa piuttosto antica:

> ...e pur d'avacciarsi, non badavasi a salire sulle piante umide. Intanto le piante si ammacchiavano, e quando giungea quell'anno che il potator vi salisse, era costretto a **tagliare di grosso**...
>
> ...somma parsimonia di tagli, e in opportuna stagione; una sola. Sfrondatura nell' anno, e totale eliminazione della scornettatura, la quale consiste nel **tagliare di grosso**, nel lasciare come a corno nel mese di maggio o di giugno i rami maestri...
>
> ...le suscettibilità della Santa Sede e della conferenza di Gaeta, troppo proclivi a credere che noi siamo disposti a **tagliare di grosso** in ciò che risguarda l'autorità e gl'interessi della Corte di Roma.

Comment: Non so cos'è la Legge Fondamentale dell'Incastro.

Comment: @Charo *Taglialo grosso e infilalo a calci*

Comment: @DenisNardin: Vuoi dire [questo](https://books.google.es/books?id=dTl9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT44&lpg=PT44&dq=%22Cut+it+large+and+kick+it+into+place%22+%22The+Basic+Law+of+Construction%22&source=bl&ots=ydPqRCJxTy&sig=fjenF_J1xDIBnW7ti51SlopZJfg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-qIrf0NDaAhUKuxQKHfjwDpgQ6AEICzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Cut%20it%20large%20and%20kick%20it%20into%20place%22%20%22The%20Basic%20Law%20of%20Construction%22&f=false)? Non mi sembra molto italiano, però.

Comment: @Charo A dir il vero non l'avevo mai sentita prima di oggi (anche se lo spirito è assai comune), ma sono certo che sia quello che LSerni intendeva.